# Is it possible to schedule refresh in Power BI with Windows Task Schedule?

Tags: powerbi, windows-task-scheduler

My Power BI report's Scheduled refresh doesn't work. So I'm trying to understand if it is possible to create a task in the Windows Task Scheduler, that opens the Power BI and refreshes the report automatically at a given time. Does anyone have experience doing this?

Comment: It is with possible with pyton https://github.com/dubravcik/pbixrefresher-python. What is wrong with the normal Scheduled Refresh?

Comment: If your PowerBI's scheduled refresh does not work, it will not work through automation. What happens when you "Refresh Now" through the PowerBI service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scheduled refresh doesn't work (you didn't said what this actually means), then the manual will not work either. But if you want to try, a PowerShell script to call the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) is an option for [refreshing a dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdatasetingroup). It uses [Microsoft Power BI Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps). Fill in the workspace and report IDs, along with your credentials, and run the script bellow:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile

$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'groups/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/datasets/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/refreshes' -Method Post

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

You can run it with Windows Task Scheduler too. Please note, that with Power BI Free you are limited to 1 refresh per 24h for a dataset or 8 times with Power BI Pro account.

But of course, it will be better to understand why your scheduled refreshes "doesn't work" first.